# How to handle push notifications on custom topic when user has logged out?

Tags: flutter, dart, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to create a delivery app with push notifications to customers when changing of order status , my notification scenario is when customer place order I write some code to subscribe him to order topic (order id) to keep track the order status , the problem is what if the customer logged out from the app , the notifications that related to the orders is still active .
what should I do in this situation ?

Comment: you can use the token based push notifications, like when the user logged out you can invalidate the token and then he will not receive the notification check out this post :https://medium.com/flutterdevs/push-notification-in-flutter-firebase-127289de5dd4

Answer (score 1):

First, you should not use topics to track a custom user notifications, use the `fmcToken` instead.
When you sign in, get the token and then asign into the user:

```dart
FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
```

And then you can send notifications to the user.

When you log out, you can:

```dart
FirebaseMessaging.instance.deleteToken();
```